# ERROR EN FUNCION POSTGRE RETURN

Tags: postgresql, funciones

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de clase y me piden que la función que multiplica tres numeros de el resultado con un RAISE NOTICE.
La funcion que tengo es esta:

```
CREATE FUNCTION multiplica_num(int, int, int) RETURNS int AS $$
DECLARE 
  num1 ALIAS FOR $1;
  num2 ALIAS FOR $2;
  num3 ALIAS FOR $3;
  result INTEGER := num1*num2*num3;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'El valor de la multiplicació és %', result;
RETURN void;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

El error que me salta es este:

> NOTICE:  El valor de la multiplicació és 6
>   ERROR:  control reached end of function without RETURN
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function multiplica_num(integer,integer,integer)
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: control reached end of function without RETURN
>   estat SQL: 2F005
>   Context:PL/pgSQL function multiplica_num(integer,integer,integer)

El problema esta en que cuando meto un RETURN no me sale el RAISE NOTICE, y el enunciado me pide explicitamente que me de el resultado mediante el RAISE NOTICE.

Comment: Es que lo que deberías retornar sería result y el mensaje lo harías fuera de la función

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que te pide es que hagas un raise notice con el resultado y no retornar nada, entonces debes definir la funcion con retorno void y no con int, algo como esto:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION multiplica_num(int, int, int) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE 
  num1 ALIAS FOR $1;
  num2 ALIAS FOR $2;
  num3 ALIAS FOR $3;
  result INTEGER := num1*num2*num3;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'El valor de la multiplicació és %', result;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Si pongo void en la primera linea después del RETURNS me devuelve una tabla con una columna vacia. Lo que estoy intentando es que me devuelva solo el RAISE NOTICE.

Comment: si lo pones como te indico, lo que hace es imprimir el RAISE NOTICE, que es para imprimir, no para devolver nada, si ejecutas esa funcion desde el psql veras que imprime el valor si lo que quieres es devolver debes siempre usar return y dejar tu funcion como esta y poner el return result en vez del return void, saludos